# Find process that created a file on windows

Tags: windows, file, process

Is there anyway to find what process created a specific file on windows?

Comment: Files persist. Processes don't. So the process may be long since dead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, no. Windows does not record the process that created a given file.

You might be able to use something like SysInternals Process Monitor, which hooks file (and registry I/O), to see if you can catch the file *being* created, but once it's created (and the last file handle is closed), Windows forgets which process it came from.

If the file is open in a process that's currently running, you can use Process Explorer (also from SysInternals) to find out which one.

If you recognise the file extension, that can sometimes help. Or, maybe you can look in the file to see if there's anything obvious in it.

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is find a match between file type and associated application on mimetypes. But even then it will only be a guess because file types can be associated to several different applications.

Another not-so-successful method will be opening the file in question and searching the header for known application names. Sometimes the app name or token can be found here, but then you need to start with a list of name strings to search for.

Answer (score -1):

Trying running **[File Activity Watch](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_activity_watch.html)** by **NirSoft** if you think it or a file like it might pop up again.